# I noticed a user using edits to get the question noticed, without adding any content (spaces)

Tags: discussion, editing

Recently I noticed in the edits that twice a user edited without posting any new content, only spaces. I think this may be an abuse of the system, but I am not sure about something, do edits on your own question get the questions bumped up in the Active question list?

Here is the edit link to the question, https://askubuntu.com/posts/113570/revisions Notice edit 3 & 4, In edit 4 the description states "just added some spaces so this can get some answers or tell why its not there" Also note that the spaces did not split the content up any, like you would expect if it was edited for readability. Leading me to believe he edited the question with no additional content just to get it noticed more.

What to do in situations like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, nothing. But, you can add a comment to that they really should add a bounty to the question. Something like this:

> `Hello! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I've noticed that you are looking for an answer, the best way of attracting attention to your question is to offer a bounty. More details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)`

Comment: Do you know if self edits bump the question up the list. If they don't I can leave this as the poster making his edit list messy. Do moderators take any action if a user is constantly doing this?

Comment: @mateo_salta Edits bump. However, bounties are a better way of doing it. As for your second one, only if it's brought to our attention, we don't go sniffing for this kind of stuff.

Comment: So, not enforced. I flagged and it was declined as something I should not notify the moderators about...

Comment: @mateo_salta The specific situation you're talking about was declined because he had added a bounty by the time we got to the flag. Sorry, I should have used a custom flag decline to fully explain.

Comment: oh, so someone may have already told him about it and the bounty as the best way to get his question noticed.

Comment: It appears that that was the case.

Comment: Also, if a user edits a question more than X number of times the question becomes a Community Wiki and they will no longer gain reputation from the question